# Replay commits from another branch that didn't make it into an MR

Tags: git, version-control

Suppose I have a branch `A` that I've been working on that corresponds to a merge request. `A` runs a few commits ahead of `origin/A` and someone else mistakenly merges this branch in. Now all the commits in `origin/A` have been flattened, and now I have to replay all these commits between `origin/A` and `A` onto a new branch created from `master` and submit a new MR for this. What's the right way to go about this? Manually I'd just cherry pick them over, but I have to imagine there's a more natural way to go about this.

Comment: 1) Create a New Branch--> 'git checkout -b new-branch origin/A' 2) Commits from Branch A onto new-branch: 'git cherry-pick A' 3) editing the conflicted files --> 'git add <conflicted-file>' 'git cherry-pick --continue' 4) Push new-branch --> 'git push origin new-branch' 5) Create a New Merge Request: Once new-branch is pushed create a new merge request for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detect what was the last commit that was **squash merged** from *your* branch and let's call that commit `X`. Once you have that, you can run:

```
git rebase X my-branch --onto the-upstream-branch
```

That way you will only rebase commits that are *after* `X`.

Comment: I think `the-upstream-branch` can be replaced with `origin/master`. I also think `git rebase origin/master A` will *probably* work, since the existing commits that were squashed will probably fall out. But your answer will *definitely* work so it is preferred. ;)

Comment: `--onto` is new to me. Thank you for the help!